# Graql shell doesn't remember queries

Tags: vaticle-typeql

After starting a mindmaps graph and connecting with the Graql shell, I try adding a type and an instance:

```
insert person isa entity-type;
insert 'carl' isa person;
```

However, when I open up the visualiser I can't see either the type or instance.

If I run a match query in the shell, I can see it just fine.

Answer (score 0):

For every `insert` or `delete` query that you write in the Graql Shell, you need to need to write `commit` command at the end. Only then will your types or instances be persisted in the graph.

So in your case it would be:

```
insert person isa entity-type;
insert 'carl' isa person;
commit
```